# Entity framework returns null when hosted

Tags: silverlight, entity-framework, hosted

I have a silverlight application where when I run the application I read the database and populate the results in the combobox, but when I publish it on the server(IIS) the it returns me a null, I can't even debug the error because it return the result when I host it on my system but null when hosted..

Please guide...

Comment: Can you show us the query that is returning null? Can you connect to the database with SQL Management Studio to check there is actual data in your hosted version?

Answer (score 0):

Taking a stab in the dark here. Most likely this is a security issue. When debugging locally, your web server runs under your credentials. If using integrated authentication to your database, then the web service host acts like it is you when making requests to the database. However, when you deploy, the server tries to connect to the database using the credential associated with the application pool that is running your site. Check your database connection string to see if it is pointing to the right database and try using a named user/password with an account that does have access to the database.

If this doesn't fix the problem, try accessing one of your services directly (using Fiddler?) to see what the service is returning as an error message that your Silverlight client is ignoring.